# With Blazor clean input content and keep focus after a tab

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

When I press `Tab` I add `MudTextField` value in a list. After that I would like clean the `MudTextField`content and keep the focus on `MudTextField`. I tried a solution with `@ref` but it's not working.

```
<MudTextField 
    @bind-Value=MyModel.MyInput
    Immediate="true"
    @onkeydown="OnKeyDown" />
    
@code {

    public MyModel MyModel { get; set; } = new();

    public void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Code == "Tab")
        {
            MyModel.MyInputs.Add(Model.MyInput);
            
            MyModel.MyInput = string.Empty;
            
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string MyInput { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<string> MyInputs { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

Update 1:

```
<CascadingValue Value=@MyModel Name="MyModel">
    <InMyCode />
    <TheCodes />
</CascadingValue>
```

The `InMyCode` component and the display of the list is in `TheCodes` in the `TheCodes` all the items are display in input text. It's may be the problem.

Comment: MudBlazor have event callback `() => TextChanged(string s)` or `OnKeyDown` and you can ignore the native calllbacks of like `@onkeydown`

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales that's the point how ignore native callbacks. When I do a tab, I would like do my stuff in OnKeyDown but keep the focus (and clean the content) on the MudTextField.

Comment: The update is not enough to understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [KeyDownPreventDefault](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield#properties:%7E:text=KeyDownPreventDefault) property.

Then we use the `preventDefault` boolean field to handle which keys should retain their default behaviour.

```
<MudTextField 
    @bind-Value="myModel.MyInput"
    Immediate ="true"
    KeyDownPreventDefault="@preventDefault"
    OnKeyDown="HandleOnKeyDown" />
    
    @if(myModel.MyInputs.Any()){
        <ol>
            @foreach(var input in myModel.MyInputs)
            {
                <li>@input</li>
            }
        </ol>
    }else{
        <h3>No inputs</h3>
    }
@code{
    public MyModel myModel { get; set; } = new();
    bool preventDefault = false;
    public void HandleOnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Tab")
        {
            preventDefault=true;
            myModel.MyInputs.Add(myModel.MyInput);
            myModel.MyInput = string.Empty;
        }
        else{
            preventDefault=false;
        }
    }
    
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string MyInput { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<string> MyInputs { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

[Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QucHkKwIqJQIeqnr)

Comment: In my project that's not work. It's may be because the structure of my component. See Update1. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've defined a `MyModel` property in your code, but then you are referencing `Model` in your `@bind-Value` attribute. This is likely just a typo in your question since it would cause a compile error, though.

By default the `MudTextField` does not update its bound value until you press enter or the input loses focus, so `Model.MyInput` will not have any value when you access it in your `OnKeyDown` event since that event fires before the input loses focus. You can overcome that using the `Immediate="true"` attribute on your `MudTextField`:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@Model.MyInput"
              Immediate="true"
              OnKeyDown="OnKeyDown" />
```